# List custom taxonomy terms sharing posts with a term from a second custom taxonomy

Tags: wp-query, custom-taxonomy, terms

I wasn't sure how to phrase my question, so I hope you understand.

I have two custom taxonomies with different terms in them.

Lets call them `custom_tax1` & `custom_tax2`.

```
custom_tax1
term1
term2
term3
...

custom_tax2
term1
term2
term3
...
```

**Question**:
Is it possible to make a list of all the terms from `custom_tax2`, that have posts tagged with `term1` from `custom_tax1`?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it's possible to directly query the terms, So I'm gonna write a workaround for you.

The `WP_Query();` accepts an argument named `terms`. You can pass term IDs as an array to this argument.

Let's first fetch a list of terms in the first taxonomy, then query based on these terms:

```
$terms = get_terms( 
    array(
       'taxonomy'   => 'custom_tax1',
       'hide_empty' => false,
       'fields'     => 'ids', // We only need the IDs
   )
);
// Now do a query
$args = array(
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'custom_tax2',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => $terms,
        ),
    ),
);
$my_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

This will query every post from `custom_tax2` that has any of the terms from `custom_tax1`. Now that you have the posts that have these terms, you can proceed with extracting terms from them.

Let's crack this down a bit further:

```
if($my_query->have_posts()){
    // Define an empty array to use later
    $post_terms = array();
    while($my_query->have_posts()){
        $my_query->the_post();
        // Merge the previous terms with the new ones
        $new_terms = wp_get_post_terms( get_the_ID(), 'custom_tax1');
        $post_terms = array_merge( $post_terms, $new_terms );
    }
}
```

Here is what happened.

1. We run a loop through all the posts belonging to `custom_tax2` taxonomy that have the terms from `custom_tax2` taxonomy.
2. We get the terms of every post in the loop
3. On each step of the loop we merge the current terms with terms from the previous post, so we end up with an array of terms from each post

Comment: Thanks, looks good, well thought! Trying to implement right now. I know how to return posts from the wp_query, but how do I output the slug for all the terms in custom_tax2 for example?

Comment: You're welcome. I've updated the answer for you.

Comment: Thanks again! For some reason nothing is returned. I am trying to figure out why

Comment: Shouldn't it be possible to do a foreach and print the slugs?

Comment: You could try and var_dump variables to see what's going wrong. Since I don't have these structure, I'm not able to test the code on my machine. By the way, which slugs do you want to do a foreach to?